# How do I produce a form with a json via javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a Json file with two type 128 and 137 . and I want to produce a form with them via javascript . I want to generate inputbox if type was 128 moreover generate selectbox if type was 137, and want to generate it dynamically.
the form that i expect to generate i s somthing like this :

```
<form action="">
  name:<br>
  <input type="text" class="input1" id="input1" data-value="0">
  <br>
  gender:<br>
  <select class="input1" id="input1" data-value="0"><option>gender</option><option value="0">famale</option><option value="1">male</option></select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

also i cannot define each attribute instead of input or selectbox's option.

I wrote the below code but it does not work.

Here is my Javascript code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < schema.length; i++) {
    var type=schema[i].type
    if(type==128){}

    if(type==137){
        var str = "<select><option>gender</option>";
        for (var j = 0; j < schema[i].values.length; j++) {
            str +="<option value='"+i+"'>"+schema[i].values[j].value.title+"</option>"
        }
        str +='</select>'
        var x=document.getElementById('option'); x.innerHTML=str;
    }
}
```

and here is my Json file :

```
 {
    "queestion":"name" ,
    "type":"128",
    "attrs":[
        {"attr":{
            "name":"class",
            "value":"input1"
        }},
        {"attr":{
            "name":"id",
            "value":"input1"
        }},
        {"attr":{
            "name":"data-value",
            "value":"0"
        }}
    ]

},
{
    "queestion":"gender" ,

    "type":"137",
    "attrs":[
        {"attr":{
            "name":"class",
            "value":"input1"
        }},
        {"attr":{
            "name":"id",
            "value":"input1"
        }},
        {"attr":{
            "name":"data-value",
            "value":"0"
        }}
    ],
    "values":[
        {"value":{
            "title":"famale",
            "value":"0"
        }},
        {"value":{
            "title":"male",
            "value":"1"
        }}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please share a copy of the JSON as well.

Comment: @JasonB updated you can see my json file now

Comment: @AniketSahrawat please see my updated question with json

Comment: Another way is to use HTML templates.

There are so many libraries which will help you to create html templates.

One of them is mustache JS.

In mustache JS, you can alter your HTML(here in your case, form) with the help of a JSON.

Below attached is the github link to the tutorials,

https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lot of issues with your code above.

First issue, your HTML does not have element with id of value "option". You need to add id with value option

```
<form action="">
  name:<br>
  <input type="text" class="input1" id="input1" data-value="0">
  <br>
  gender:<br>
  <select class="input1" id="option" data-value="0"></select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Second issue, check line

```
str +="<option value='"+i+"'>"+schema[i].values[j].value.title+"</option>"
```

should be replaced by

```
str +="<option value='"+j+"'>"+schema[i].values[j].value.title+"</option>"
```

Check updated javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < schema.length; i++) {
    var type=schema[i].type;
    if(type==128){}

    if(type==137){
        var str = "<select><option>gender</option>";
        for (var j = 0; j < schema[i].values.length; j++) {
            str +="<option value='"+j+"'>"+schema[i].values[j].value.title+"</option>"
        }
        str +='</select>'
        var x=document.getElementById('option'); x.innerHTML=str;
    }
}
```

Comment: how to add atrribute of select?

Comment: tank you! how can generate input ?

Comment: What I would recommend is provide an id to the form. Generate whatever you want dynamically based on 128 or 137. And insert the string inside the form. Also, it is a bad idea to have multiple elements having the same id

Comment: See if you wrap this in a loop     var str = "<input " + schema[i].attrs[0].attr.name + "='" + schema[i].attrs[0].attr.value + "' " +
        schema[i].attrs[1].attr.name + "='" + schema[i].attrs[1].attr.value + "' " +
        schema[i].attrs[2].attr.name + "=" + schema[i].attrs[2].attr.value  + " />";

Answer (score 0):

here is the final soultion:

```js
var schema = [{
    "queestion":"name" ,
    "type":"128",
    "attrs":[
        {"attr":{
            "name":"class",
            "value":"input1"
        }},
        {"attr":{
            "name":"id",
            "value":"input1"
        }},
        {"attr":{
            "name":"data-value",
            "value":"0"
        }}
    ]

},{
    "queestion":"gender" ,

    "type":"137",
    "attrs":[
        {"attr":{
            "name":"class",
            "value":"input1"
        }},
        {"attr":{
            "name":"id",
            "value":"input1"
        }},
        {"attr":{
            "name":"data-value",
            "value":"0"
        }}
    ],
    "values":[
        {"value":{
            "title":"famale",
            "value":"0"
        }},
        {"value":{
            "title":"male",
            "value":"1"
        }}
    ]
}]

for (var i = 0; i < schema.length; i++) {
 var type=schema[i].type;
 if(type==128){ 
  var titleinput=schema[i].queestion; 
  var divtitle=document.getElementById('input'); 
 divtitle.innerHTML=titleinput + " : "; 
 var string = "<input "; 
 for (var y=0;y<schema[i].attrs.length;y++){ 
  string += schema[i].attrs[y].attr.name+'="'+schema[i].attrs[y].attr.value+'" ' 
 } 
 string+=">"; 
 console.log(string) 
 var y=document.getElementById('addinput'); 
 y.innerHTML=string; 
}
if(type==137){
var titleinput=schema[i].queestion; 
  var divtitle=document.getElementById('select'); 
 divtitle.innerHTML=titleinput + " : "; 
 var str = "<select><option>gender</option>";
 for (var j = 0; j < schema[i].values.length; j++) {
  str +="<option value='"+schema[i].values[j].value.value+"'>"+schema[i].values[j].value.title+"</option>"
 }
 str +='</select>'
 var x=document.getElementById('option'); x.innerHTML=str;
}
}
```

```css
.container{
  display : flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="input"></div><div id="addinput"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="select"></div><div id="option"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: in the end you need to do this   var x=document.getElementById('option'); x.innerHTML=str; for that if block, i did not know where exactly you wanted to attach it so let it for you.

Comment: if(type==128){ 
        var string = "<input ";
        for (var y=0;y<schema[i].attrs.length;y++){
            string += schema[i].attrs[y].attr.name+'="'+schema[i].attrs[y].attr.value+'" '
        }
        string+=">";
        var y=document.getElementById('addinput'); 
        y.innerHTML=string;
    }

Comment: ok first console log the string variable to check if the tag created is proper or not, paste it here so we can verify the input tag is generated properly, next while attaching the tag to a element,if innerHtml is not working , change the approach and use dom manipulations statements likeinstead of u.innerHTML=string do y.appendChild(string); let me know what is happening, with these approaches.

Comment: I saw it with the console.log. Now I have to do it. How do I paste it on the page

Comment: how pasted it here?

Comment: if(type==128){ 

     var titleinput=schema[i].queestion
        var divtitle=document.getElementById('input');
        divtitle.innerHTML=titleinput;


        var string = "<input ";
        for (var y=0;y<schema[i].attrs.length;y++){
            string += schema[i].attrs[y].attr.name+'="'+schema[i].attrs[y].attr.value+'" '
        }
   
        string+=">";
        console.log(string)
         var y=document.getElementById('addinput'); 
         y.innerHTML=string;
        
  }

Comment: Yes @Hadis I ran ur code commenting the .innerHTML command, it is working fine. If it is still not working can u do it in jsFiddle or if u want ill show it in jsFiddle.

Comment: @Hadis I have done the JsFiddle let me know if this is what you want. https://jsfiddle.net/wvyuyay7/

Comment: tank you very much

Comment: hi! I need your help

Comment: Yes tell me... @Hadis

Comment: i want to repeat a div In exchange for type 128 . I have several type=128

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < schema.length; i++) {
    var type=schema[i].type;
    if(type==128){
    for (var y=0;y<schema[i].type.length;y++){ 
            var string = "<div class="c-infoo"><label for="family" class="abs-tlt"> "; 
            string += schema[i].queestion;
        string+="</label>";
        var y=document.getElementsByClassName('adultInfoes'); 
        y.innerHTML=string + " : ";

Comment: var string1 = "<_input "; 
        for (var x=0;x<schema[i].attrs.length;x++){ 
            string += schema[i].attrs[x].attr.name+'="'+schema[i].attrs[x].attr.value+'" ' 
        } 
        string1+=">"; 
        console.log(string) 
        var y=document.getElementsByClassName('adultInfoes'); 
        y.innerHTML=string1;    
    } 
    }
}

Comment: <div class="c-infoo">
    <label for="family" class="abs-tlt">lastname</label>
    <input placeholder=" lastname" id="family" name="_root.passengerinfo__1.passengerinfo.fullname.lastname" class="nofilling2 engword" type="text">
   </div>

Comment: Are you helping me?Did you notice that I mean?

Comment: Sorry... was afk due to some work, so u have multiple type 128 and others and need to loop through them right?

Comment: also if possible share the json with multiple type 128 data and Ill provice the new updated code... sorry for delay...